# Unable to get any error in Proteus 8

Tags: proteus

[image: Faulty Circuit]

Okay so I am new to Proteus Simulation software.

I made the above displayed circuit but cant seem to get any errors. If I make all the right connection the LED works but it shouldn't as LED is 20mA and I am passing current of more than 100 Amp..

Any idea why Proteus does not show any breakdowns ???

Comment: Not familiar with Proteus, but all the Spice simulators I used so far did not include any self-heating, breakdown or overstress simulation. Even saturation effects in inductors are rarely found. That's all part of the engineers work (to know the limits of the parts).

Answer (score 2):

SPICE simulators require that you have a ground port inserted into every circuit for reference, usually connected to the negative side of the battery. It also looks like you've installed both a current source and a battery array?  I'm not sure what you expected there. Also one end of the batteries isn't connected to anything.